# Method to wait until element is displayed, but need to pass the element as a parameter to make it a generic method to be used

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to create a generic method to be used across the test suite. This method should take the web element as a parameter. Then the method should return `true` or `false` based on the visibility of it during the configured time out.

```
public bool WaitForElementVisibility(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    try
    {
        //code to wait until element is displayed similar to this. But instead of passing By.Id(login) pass the element
        new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm creating a framework in selenium, C#.
You can see my progress in this https://umangamadawala.blogspot.com/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How to implement the body to pass an element to check whether the element is displayed.

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));

Comment: @HimBromBeere did you understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are searching something like this code:

You can pass your By.Id("Login") as a By element without any problem, so the call to this function will be something like:

WaitUntilElementVisible(By.Id("Login")); and if you want to change in this call the timeout time you will call like this: WaitUntilElementVisible(By.Id("Login"),45);

You cam put there your Try and catch logic. I use ElementIsVIsible but you can use ElementExist only changing the call.

```
protected virtual IWebElement WaitUntilElementVisible(By elementLocator, int timeout = 30)
        {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));

                return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(elementLocator));

        }
```